# Creating a migration when factoring out a new model out of an already existing one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

I have some code like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  something = models.ForeignKey('SomethingElse')
  property1 = models.TextField()
  city = models.TextField()
  street = models.TextField()
  country = models.TextField()
```

And I would like to shape it like this:

```
class Address(models.Model):
  city = models.TextField()
  street = models.TextField()
  country = models.TextField()

class Item(models.Model):
  something = models.ForeignKey('SomethingElse')
  property1 = models.TextField()
  address = models.ForeignKey('Address')
```

When trying to migrate the Project, Django asks me to create a default value. How could I specify one? Alternatively, how could I create a migration that creates addresses based on what we already have in the DB and then tie those to items?

Comment: Have you looked at : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Comment: @stellasia: I hadn't, but it looks interesting - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Migrations only deal with the table structure, they can't move the data for you:

> Django can’t automatically generate data migrations for you, as it does with schema migrations, but it’s not very hard to write them.

You should add the `Address` model *before* making this change, manually migrate your data, and *then* remove the redundant fields from `Item` model. You can use [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to include these changes in your migrations.

Comment: And I cannot describe this step within the migration code?

Comment: Yes you can, see [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) for details.